# Difference and relationship between the hibernate session and connection pool?

Tags: hibernate, session, connection

I am confused about the hibernate session and connection pool, are they the same thing?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Hibernate is an ORM, it is a layer between a SQL database and your POJOs.

A connection pool provides a way to store and reuse `java.sql.Connection` instances for speed and robustness.

A hibernate `Session` is a wrapper around a `Connection` in order to allow you to save your POJOs without directly writing the SQL.

So a hibernate `Session` is a wrapper around a `Connection`. `Connection`s are held in a connection pool.

When you call `SessionFactory.openSession` hibernate first takes a `Connection` from the supplied connection pool. It then creates a `Session` around that `Connection` and returns it.

Comment: Does it close the connection on closing the session?

Comment: @user_mda you should not be thinking about connections when using JPA. It can do what it wants under the hood. Practically speaking it would probably call `close` on the `Connection`, yes, but that's an implementation detail.

Comment: what is the difference between session.close() and session.flush()?

Comment: but HibernateUtil.getNewSession() does not create a new connection？